# "http" and "?" are getting cutoff in android webview mailto links

Tags: android, mailto

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Don't create another webview reference here,
    // just use the one you declared at class level.
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String     description, String failingUrl)
        {
        // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
          if(url.startsWith("mailto:")){
              MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
              Intent i = newEmailIntent(HelloWorld.this, mt.getBody(), mt.getSubject());
              startActivity(i);
              view.reload();
              return true;
        }

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

   });
}
public static Intent newEmailIntent(Context context, String body, String subject ) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.setType("rfc2368/html");
    return intent;
   }
}
```

Trying to add a mailto to a webview application.  When you run the application and click a mailto link it opens up the messenger.  For some reason "http" and "?" are getting cut off and not recognized by the mailto.  The same mailto link works perfect in devices normal browser.  The only field I need to get are subject and body.

Comment: Can you identify at which point the mailto link is getting mangled?

Comment: <a href="mailto:?body=Send%20Link%20http://www.example.com/exampletype?0123456%20&amp;subject=Link">Email</a>   From this example the only thing that is showing in the body of the mailto message is "/exampletype"  Everything before the / and starting at ? and after missing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. At what point **in your code** does the link get screwed up, to figure this out you should display the URL string at all the places it is used using logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Good bet: Make sure any of the content in the mailto link subject/body fields are URL escaped (no literal slashes, ampersands, etc.) when they get to the `MailTo` parsing code. "`?`" in particular is a reserved character for headers in the [Mailto RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368).

That is, not

```
mailto://...subject=http://foo.com?x=y
```

but instead try

```
mailto://...subject=http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com%3Fx%3Dy
```

Comment: I changed out the forward slashes and questions marks with the correct url encoding and am still not getting the body and subject prefilled.